# Should this question about what happens if the Pope is physically or mentally incapacitated have been closed as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I recently asked the question [What happens if a Pope is unable to continue his duties due to physical or mental illness?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/66365/16688). To my surprise, it was closed as a duplicate of [Could the Pope be removed from office for lapses in judgment?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/66120/16688).

I'm not seeing how these two are related. One is due to becoming physically or mentally incapacitated, another is about decisions he makes. I'm not seeing the connection or why these are duplicates.

Should this question have been closed as a duplicate?

Comment: Already reopened.